# Join records coming at different times to Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Have the requirements as this. Records in the control table (database table) with customer number and promotion code as key is published in topic say T1. Records in email table (database table) with customer number as key is published in a topic say T2. Matching records for customer number might be published in the topics T1 and T2 at different times.

**Solution attempted**

Part 1 - Read T1 as stream and T2 as GlobalKTable. Join the two using the below snippet. This works fine when a new record is pushed in T1 and a look up happens in T2 using the customer number as foreign key

T1.join(T2, T1.customerNumber, joiner).

Part 2 - Read T2 as stream and T1 as GlobalKTable. Trying to join the records does not work here.

T2.join(T1, **cannot build key for T1 from T2 record here**, joiner). The solution breaks here.

Both the above parts form the complete solution. The solution would make sure that even if records are published at different times a lookup in GlobalKTable will get a matching record.

Is this the right solution for the requirement or is their a better solution. Currently part 2 of the solution is not working. Please advise.

Comment: As both input are tables, why do you not do a table-table join?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Since each consumer is assigned a partition for processing (correct my understanding if not right).
KTable consumer for Partion 1 of Topic T1 (Key - C1, P1, Value - V1)
KTable consumer for Partion 2 of Topic T1 (Key - C1, P2, Value - V2)
KTable consumer for Partion 1 of Topic T2 (Key - C1, Value - C1@email.com)
**Expected Output is two records for the above data set**
1. Output Key - (C1, P1) Output Value - (V1, C1@email.com) - Working
2. Output Key - (C1, P2) Output Value - (V2, C1@email.com) - **Might not work since key (C1, P2) for T2 might be in Partion 2**

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Can you share how the KTable-KTable would work if we want to join the scenario mentioned in part 2 of the question assuming we read both the topics as KTable?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-join

Comment: If you do a FK-join, Kafka Streams will ensure that the joins happens across partitions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-213+Support+non-key+joining+in+KTable

Comment: Yes @MatthiasJ.Sax. If we look at the attempted solution, the FK-join is applied to Part 1 of the solution. For the Part 2 of the solution, the FK to join cant be built. 

As an alternate can we consider using KStream-KTable combination for the solution. If so the FK can be built for the part 2 of the solution. In that case how will the partitions work if we replace GlobalKTable with KTable. Please suggest.